# How to find line in javascript that is failing or causing javascript to crash/not continue execution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, debugging, phpstorm

Ok, im more of backend programmer so i have very little to no experience on the front-end.

I know when javascript execution has failed due to a bug, like when the page doesn't render properly(due to some javascript code) etc, so how do i find the bug in javascript code? I'm using simple notepad++.

Comment: browser tools such as firebug

Comment: what about if your using chrome?

Comment: F12 brings up the dev tools. The console should tell you what errored and where.

Comment: chrome has dev tools built in: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: IE and FF both have dev tools built in too.

Comment: Or post some code to have others help debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers have developer tools.  Hit F12 and there is a good chance it will pop up.  Use the console tab to view error output and use the source tab to add breakpoints and watch variables.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you:
(1)open development view of your web browser and check the console to see if there are warnings/errors which ruined your script;
(2)if there is no errors, check your code again and see if there are infinite loops or problems like this; then comment out some seem-bad lines and check the code by using console.log() or alert().

Some good tools are truly helpful like firebug. Tutorials abounds. It takes some getting used to, but it will help a lot when you use properly.
http://cs-server.usc.edu:45678/resources/tutorials/firebug-571.pdf
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch errors in Javascript using `try`-`catch`. This piece of code work in Chrome, I didn't tested in other browsers.

```
try {
    undefinedFunction();
} catch(err) {
    alert(err.message + new Error().stack);
}
```

Comment: The developer tools really are a better option

Comment: He is using a simple Notepad++. This solution can be used with Notepad++. I know that Developer tools are better. I've tested my code in it before posting it here :)

Comment: He already state he's running Chrome.  If you happen to be running javascript from the command line, like with NodeJS chances are any errors notifications will already be written out to the console.  The notices usually include a reason and line number.